# How do I optimize C code using loop transformation?

Tags: c, for-loop, optimization

[image: code here]

loop fusion, does it mean the above code will become

```
   for(j=1; j<=4,j++){
         a[j]=3;
         a[j]=a[j]*2*h;
         b[j]=6;
         b[j]=b[j]+3*k*k;
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from using two separate loops, the original code contains lots of redundant statements. One possible improvement would be this:

```
int tmp = 6 * h;
for (j = 1; j <= 4; j++) {
     a[j] = tmp;
     b[j] = 6 + 3 * j * j;
}
```

The main optimizations:

- One loop instead on two
- Removed assignments that get overwritten in the next statement
- Calculate a value that does not depend on the loop index outside the loop

You should be aware that most of these optimizations would be done by a compiler anyways.

Comment: Good answer, Frank, but he should have done his homework himself, so he learns. Better to vote to close these questions.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie: You are mistaken. http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147100/155739

Comment: @PaulOgilvie: I did hesitate before answering the question, exactly for this reason. But then, I hope that he will learn something from the answer. He will still have to count the numbers of operations and by doing this, will have to think about the differences of the two implementations.

Comment: @FrankPuffer  thank you... this is really not a homework question, i have no knowledge about c++ so im confuse with the codes. i'm just trying to understand how loop transformation works and how does it help to reduce overhead because i'm studying embedded system